# The best split for an inheritance

Tags: co.combinatorics, combinatorial-optimization

I am trying to figure out algorithms for solving the following problem:
I have a set of assets $A = \{ a_i : i = 1\ldots n \}$ which I want to split between two agents $v$ and $w$, the value of each asset for each agent is $v_i = v(a_i)$ and $w_i = w(a_i)$. So I am looking for two disjoint, complementary sets $A^v$ and $A^w$, $A^v \cup A^w = A$, of given cardinality ($n$ and $n-k$ say) such that $$\sum_{a \in A^v} v(a) + \sum_{a\in A^w}w(a)$$ Be a maximum.
Otherwise say I want to split my inheritage in a way that the happiness of my two kids will be maximum. Any pointer will be much appreciated.

Comment: The common sense solution (find the k items v likes the most compared to w, i.e. where $v(a) - w(a)$ is largest) works.

Comment: Indeed that a good hint, I missed thath